Beta decay in perturbation theory
I'm trying to calculate the probability that an electron stays in the ground state after decay, with the nucleus going from Z=1 to Z=2.I've seen that, due to the fast change in the Hamiltonian, we could consider the instantaneous approximation and simply calculate the overlap of the wave functions. However, what if I don't want to make an approximation? Could I simply consider the final H minus the initial H as the perturbing potential and calculate the coefficients as usual?

In this problem, the Hamiltonian of an electron in an atom depends on time, $\hat{H}(t)$. To simplify the problem, it is natural to assume that the transition from $Z = 2$ to $Z = 1$ occurs instantaneously. Otherwise, it is hardly possible to write $\hat{H}(t)$. And under the assumption of instantaneous decay, the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}(t)$ corresponds to the charge of the nucleus $Z=2$ before the decay and corresponds to $Z=1$ after the decay. In any case, with or without the assumption of instantaneous decay, there is no point in considering the difference between the final and initial Hamiltonians, since you are interested in the probabilities of finding the electron in the ground state of the final Hamiltonian. At the same time, if we consider the decay of the nucleus to be instantaneous, then we can assume that the electron wave function has not changed during the decay, and this makes it possible to further solve the problem.

How does the Hamiltonian depend on the time? Consider a bohr atom

I described how the Hamiltonian depends on time. Beta decay of a nucleus occurs at some time, say $t_0$. Before the decay, that is, at $t < t_0$, you have a one-electron Bohr atom with nuclear charge Z = 2, and a one-electron Bohr atom with nuclear charge Z = 1 after the decay, at $t > t_0$. I assume you know the form of the Bohr atom Hamiltonian for an arbitrary nuclear charge Z.
